# How to create gantt chart in lotus connections

Tags: lotus, connection, gantt-chart

there is a way to create a Gantt chart of an activity in lotus connections? Or is there a way to create a graph lotus connections in collecting information from the database that stores the contents of the lotus connections?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Connections API to retrieve data and build a widget. See http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/lcwiki.nsf/dx/Retrieving_activity_nodes_ic301 on how to retrieve activity data.